# how to define service runlevel order position?

Tags: mysql, bind, runlevel

I setup bind-dlz and need mysql start prior NAMED when system starts
here is what I have

```
[root@semenov]# ./test.sh   
mysql           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
named           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Apr 15 18:57 /etc/rc3.d/S93mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Apr 15 18:57 /etc/rc3.d/S90named -> ../init.d/named
```

here is what I have in mysql init script

```
# Comments to support chkconfig on RedHat Linux
# chkconfig: 2345 84 16
# description: A very fast and reliable SQL database engine.

# Comments to support LSB init script conventions
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: mysql
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Should-Start: ypbind nscd ldap ntpd xntpd
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop MySQL
# Description: MySQL is a very fast and reliable SQL database engine.
### END INIT INFO
```

so when I remove named from chkconfig and have there just mysql, it starts with order number 84: /etc/rc3.d/S84mysql -> ../init.d/mysql

but when I add named inside chkconfig it's order changes to 93: /etc/rc3.d/S93mysql -> ../init.d/mysql

as a result mysql will be starting after named and named will fail (no sql available)

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

here is what I have in named init script

```
# chkconfig: 345 90 16
# description: named (BIND) is a Domain Name Server (DNS) \
# that is used to resolve host names to IP addresses.
# probe: true

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: $named
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $syslog
# Default-Start:2 3 4
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
# Short-Description: start|stop|status|restart|try-restart|reload|force-reload DNS     server
# Description: control ISC BIND implementation of DNS server
### END INIT INFO
```

thanks,
Dmitry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the `chkconfig(8)` manpage, it favors LSB `Required-Start` and `Required-Stop` over the `# chkconfig:` line, if it is available:

```
Note that default entries in LSB-delimited 'INIT INFO' sections take
precedence over the default runlevels in the initscript; if any
Required-Start or Required-Stop entries are present, the start and
stop priorities of the script will be adjusted to account for these
dependencies.
```

You should be able to add `mysql` to the `Required-Start` section of the `named` LSB `INIT INFO` section and re-add it using `chkconfig --add`.